How to make a Hyper-v virtual machine under OpenWrt have internet access?
The host machine being connected through Wifi or Ethernet. Is the procedure the same?

I'd imagine this would be pretty simple to test. Have you tested it yet? I think also you may be overthinking things. To a VM on a connected physical host it really doesn't matter what firmware the wireless router is running, so long as the host is connect.

I've tried to use the Default Switch and to make my own NAT Switch but nothing works so far. I can't ping anything in OpenWrt.
